# Custom draw UIView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a modified UIView that I am using to display rich text (NSAttributedString). I am adding the UIView to my UITableViewCell and drawRect is being executed. I overrided that method in order to show text.

The problem is that in the row #3 it writes the text that I want but below it the old text is still there.

The same happens with all the other cells.

How can I clear my UIView for each cell?

This is my drawrect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   [super drawRect:rect];
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
   CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

   CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
   CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds );

   CTFramesetterRef framesetter =
   CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)self.attString); 

   CTFrameRef frame =

   CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,

                         CFRangeMake(0, [self.attString length]), path, NULL);

   CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4
   CFRelease(frame); //5
   CFRelease(path);
   CFRelease(framesetter);

}
```

And here is how I am adding it in cellforrowatindexpath:

```
 NSAttributedString* attrString = [p attrStringFromMarkup:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ %@%@ %@%@", @"<font color=\"black\">", userName, @"<font color=\"gray\">",actionType,  @"<font color=\"black\">", object]];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 249, 50);
CTView *aView = [[CTView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
[aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[(CTView*)aView setAttString: attrString];
[cell.feedView addSubview:aView];
```

Comment: The old text should be cleared automatically. Is the `drawRect` in `UIView` or `UITableViewCell`? Can you post the code that is doing this?

Comment: UIView. I will post my code now

Comment: Have you tried to draw an empty rectangle with the size equal to the cell before drawing the text? And fill it with the background color of your cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the CTView only once after creating the UITableViewCell and then reuse it with the cell. Otherwise you would add the CTView multiple times to the same cell.

The code should look like that:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 249, 50);
   CTView *aView = [[CTView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
   [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   [aView setTag:kCTViewTag];
   [cell.feedView addSubview:aView];
}

// Configure the cell...
 NSAttributedString* attrString = [p attrStringFromMarkup:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ %@%@ %@%@", @"<font color=\"black\">", userName, @"<font color=\"gray\">",actionType,  @"<font color=\"black\">", object]];

CTView* view = (CTView*)[cell viewWithTag:kCTViewTag];
[view setAttString:attrString];
```

The `setAttString` method should invoke `[self setNeedsDisplay]`.